# Can't compile rtmidi test cmidiin.cpp file, Illegal instruction

Tags: c++, armbian

I'm using Armbian on the Orange Pi board. I try to compile cmidiin.cpp from test folder of the rtmidi lib. Compiling goes with no error messages. But when I run it shows me:

```
g++ cmidiin.cpp -o t6 -g -lpthread -lasound  -lrtmidi
./t6
Opening f_midi:f_midi 20:0
Illegal instruction
```

BUT! When I compile it with make command from rtmidi, it works fine.
Seems that I don't use some parameters or keys, when I compile. Any ideas how I can fix it? Or how I can get info, what parameters use "make" file? Because now when I run it, I can see only two lines:

```
CXX      cmidiin.o
CXXLD    cmidiin
```

[rtmidi site](https://www.music.mcgill.ca/%7Egary/rtmidi/)

Comment: Are you asking that somebody downloads the make file, interprets it for you and tells you the commandline to build without make? It seems that woudl contradict the idea of a provided makefile... and of StackOverflow.

Comment: Try running `make V=1` to show the full compiler invocation; it seems the configure script uses the common `AM_SILENT_RULES` module to hide compile output unless requested.

Comment: > Are you asking that somebody downloads the make file, interprets it for you and tells you the commandline to build without make?
Of course no, @Yunnosch.
Seems that advice with "make V=1" will help me. Thank you, @Botje!

Answer (score 0):

Ok, now test file works fine with this command:

```
g++ -Wall cmidiin.cpp -o t7 /usr/local/lib/librtmidi.so
```

Very strange that it don't work with -lrtmidi key, and work, when I indicate full path to the lib.

Comment: Is it possible your `-lrtmidi` was picking up another `rtmidi.so` somewhere? You can check with `ldd t6`. (unless it picked up a static library of course...)